# text Multisearch in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i need to do a text ASP.NET (C#) multisearch textbox  (i.e. to allow to choose and input 3 values  as i.e: "one,two,three"  ) autocomplete with suggestion  like Google Search in my database and meantime is inputting the value in the text the datagrid will show the data present in our database ...
Do you have any advises or idea to make it right?

Thanks so much for your attention

Cheers

Edited :

I am trying to do it with c# and not jquery as requested and not jquery.

Thanks so much.

Comment: For client-side operation you're going to most likely need jQuery or Javascript. You certainly can't implement this with _only_ C#.

Comment: What you special ask, needs too many tricks, special cache, and a lot of speed that you can not have and make it like google. You can simple place an updatepanel that refress with every key press and see the results.

Comment: @aristos yes but i just got stuck in an error so i am trying to work out it.Thanks alot

Comment: for autocomplete you could probably write a WCF service that returns a JSON object (or simple string with comma separated values) with autocomplete values, which you populate on the page by JavaScript/jQuery. Also, add your table/GridView to an UpdatePanel and update data when a new completed word is added to the search field. Would this work for you?

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy to others...

Answer (score 5):

You could use Jquery UI's AutoComplete functionality:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Comment: @Koerner thanks i qould ask you if with AJAX autocomplete can implement the same feature(C#) as the link that you sent me .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AjaxToolKit AutoComplete extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

You'll definitely get the answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use jQuery I would recommend the AJAX autocomplete extender.  Really useful and you can do all of your query code in C# using a web method.  Check out the [article](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) here.

Comment: yes but the trouble is when i choose the first value and add the comma i want choose the second value but the autocomplete Ajax dont show me the second choose...

Comment: More than likely you need to alter your autocomplete extender to include an onKeyDown event that triggers the comma in order restart the autocomplete process.  The AJAX control is open source so you should be able to alter it.  See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290865/comma-or-semicolon-delimited-autocomplete-textbox) here.

Comment: or you can simply have 3 textboxes, one for each word

Answer (score 0):

For the autocomplete portion you will need `AJAX Control Toolkit AutoCompleteExtender`: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

And for the search portion you will need `SQL Server Full Text Search`: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/autocomplete/autocomplete.aspx which supports coma separated search.

It takes time to load the list but it does load list.

You can even try http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/multivalue-autocomplete-winforms-textbox-for-tagging/ the sample is for Winform would have to convert into Webform.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: AJAX Control Toolkit is going the way of the dinosaur. [http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx). It is still functional, but don't hold your breath on support.

Comment: not quite, updates are far and few between, but still coming - if you  want the latest MS supported alternative (AJAX server controls based on JQuery), check out Juice UI Autocomplete: http://juiceui.com/controls/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Textbox, ajax toolkit AutoComp xtender will do it for you. To do so:

1. Create a WebMethod or Page method.
2. Call your select query in that method.
3. Call that in your Ajax toolkit Autocomplete Extender via ToolkitScriptmanager.

Above is just to show you a way out,, rest you will get by googling.
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/ajax-autocompleteextender-sample.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use AjaxToolKit AutoComplete extender.

Check following link. All resources in following link.
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

And this is code project example link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit

Answer (score 0):

Real quick - you need "&" between your key/value pairs, so change to:

```
Response.Redirect("~SearchResults.aspx?Weight=" + txtWeight.Text + "&Height=" + txtHeight.Text + "&Age=" + txtAge1.Text + txtAge2.Text + "&Country=" + ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
```

As for your SearchResult.aspx, you need to retrieve the values with QueryString, so something like:

```
string Weight = Request.QueryString["Weight"];
string Height = Request.QueryString["Height"];

...and so on. You use the key from the redirect and the value is returned (setting your string variables).
```

As for your query, what are you tables, and what exactly are you looking for in terms of results? I understand you have these criteria, but are you looking for something that is exactly as what these criteria are? Or close to? I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for JQuery auto complete and JqGrid to display the matching data.

You can never do a redirect because you want to stay on the same page and just want to update portions of the page dynamically.

If you have a chance to use MVC 4 particularly the WEB API then it would be brilliant, if not a webmethod that accepts and returns json data will be nice.

http://www.asp.net/web-api

I personally will not use ajaxtoolkit for this, the closer your code is to HTML, the better you're off.

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete textbox search implemented using webmethod with database search result.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=yourserver;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=yourdatabase;User Id=youruserid;Password=yourpassword"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Name from Company where Name LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                result.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

for more details http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-create-autocomplete-textbox-with-database-in-asp-net-c/1254